# using in_category rather than query_posts in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

In wordpress I have a page template called news that I want to display all the posts from one category - 'News'. I don't want to use the category.php because there is a massive blog on the site already.

```
 query_posts('cat=145');  
 while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
 //do something
 endwhile;
```

Works fine but I have read that query_posts has drawbacks (like speed)

I tried doing this but it just showed me nothing:

```
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
if ( in_category( '145' ) ) : //also tried 'News'
//do something
```

Why doesn't' in_category work here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try this code:

```
$args = array('post_type' => 'post',
        'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'category',
                        'field'    => 'slug',
                        'terms'    => 'news'  // please pass here you news category slugs 
                    ),
                )
        );

    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
        print_r($post);
    endwhile;

    wp_reset_postdata();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could WP Query for achieving your requirement.

Documentation: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters
Example:

```
<?php
$args = array(
  'cat' => 145,
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>

<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

  <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
  <?php endwhile; ?>

  <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: real sorry - its not working. If I put an echo statement after the while it prints out so there are posts,  but I can't get the_title to show anything

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [get_posts()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) function:

```
$get_p_args = array('category'=> 145,'posts_per_page'=>-1);

$myposts = get_posts( $get_p_args );
foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
    <div>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; 
wp_reset_postdata();?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
global $wp_query;
$args = array_merge( $wp_query->query_vars, array(
    'post_type' => 'post', // You can add a custom post type if you like
    'paged' => $paged,
    'posts_per_page' => 6, // limit of posts
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'orderby' => 'publish_date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'lang' => 'en', // use language slug in the query
) );
query_posts( $args );
```